# c++11 Using regex for input validation

Tags: c++11

I have been looking forever how I can use Regex to validate input for c++ 11. What I basically would like is a piece of code that validates a number input within a specific range (for this example lets say 0-9). It should only allow numbers that I want the user to enter within the range. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you done any research so far?  I'll bet I could find an answer here on Stack Overflow which comes pretty close to exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes I have. But i find it frustrating that I cant find anything I can piece together to get to work.

Comment: The regex to match a single digit is trivial (`\d` or `[0-9]`).  As for the C++ code, any regex C++ question should suffice.